# I am trying to do an if statement with the input to be 21 and the result be Time printed out

Tags: python, variables, testing, syntax

So first of all I want to know is there something that goes `if Hello = 18` `print Hello`.

My code looks like this I want it to print out time which is already a working variable. I want `if Hello = 21` but it doesn't do =. I also want to know why I can't just do print Time.

```
Hello = (input("What is 10 + 9 "))
if Hello > 20:
print Time`
```

Comment: You should check out the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial) and read up on assigning variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime

hello = input("What is 10+9?")

if hello > 20:
   print(datetime.datetime.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `==` operator , that is the one for checking equality.

Example -

```
Hello = int(raw_input("What is 10 + 9 "))
if hello == 21: print Time
```

Also, since you are using *Python 2.x* , you should use `raw_input()` and then convert it to `int` (As i did above).

`input()` in Python 2.x evaluates whatever is inputted, which may be dangerous.